# How do I insert multiple lines in command mode in VIM

Tags: vim

I want to paste multiple lines in command mode. (After the colon) How can I do this?
When pasting either a `^m` pops out or just pastes the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:bar

`|` can be used to separate commands, so you can give multiple commands in one
line. If you want to use `|` in an argument, precede it with `\`.

Answer (score 1):

As you're trying to paste some text, it must be in a register already. I assume it is unnamed register then to execute it press <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>@</kbd>

And, no, you cannot just insert it into the cmdline unless you've replaced all CRs with | (and even then it may not work properly depending on the command you paste).

Answer (score 0):

You can put a range like this:

```
:for i in range(1,255) | put='192.168.0.' . i | endfor
```

Or if you have a text on the clipboard:

```
:0put +
```